# Word for confusing one emotion for another

Tags: single-word-requests, psychology

I'm trying to think of a word for one someone, at the feeling of one emotion; say, sadness or despair, reacts in another such as anger and frustration. Seeing as they don't act in a manner that suggests sadness, their actions confuse people on their emotions.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Alexithymia/Alexithymic is about having difficulty distinguishing emotions in both oneself and others. It's not per se what you're describing, but surely a close cousin and plausible underlying cause.

Comment: Maybe they are complex, not one dimensional....

Answer (score 1):

I experience sadness, but no despair, in pointing out that your Question makes no sense.

*… at the feeling of one emotion…* means what, please? Is your *one emotion* felt by the someone, or by his interlocutor?

*… at the feeling of one emotion… reacts* suggests the one emotion was felt by the interlocutor but that’s not consistent with the rest.

Generally when I feel an emotion, I feel it. I don’t *react in (or with) another*. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

To **misread** [a situation] is a *"word for confusing one emotion for another"*:

> *to judge a situation wrongly*[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misread)
>
> Example: *I thought he liked me, but I'd completely misread the signals*[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misread).